# Sketch $y=2x^3/(x^2-2)$

Tags: functions

> Sketch the curve $$y=\frac{2x^3}{x^2-2}.$$

Can someone answer this for me as basic as possible. Year 11 extension if possible. Thanks

Comment: Instead of saying "Year 11 extension" (which no one from a different school system will understand), say what math you have done. In particular, have you learned about asymptotes? Have you done any Calculus?

Comment: How might you be able so simplify the equation? [And here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: We've done asymptotes and are yet to do calculus

Comment: [Please use WolframAlpha responsibly](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cfrac%7B2x%5E3%7D%7Bx%5E2-2%7D) :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Firstly, simplify the equation
   $$\frac{2x^3}{x^2-2}=2x+\frac{4x}{x^2-2}.$$
   Now, we can get the asymptotes to be $y=2x$ since as $x\rightarrow\pm\infty$, the second term on the RHS tends to zero. Also, notice that if $x=\pm\sqrt{2}$, the function would be undefined, so we have 3 asymptotes
   $$y=2x, x=\pm\sqrt{2}.$$
2. Now, we need to find turning points which can be done by differentiating the function and solving for zeroes (I'll leave them to you).
3. Find the $x$ and $y$ intercepts by substituting $x=0$ and $y=0$ into the equation.

Comment: But OP hasn't done Calculus, so Step 2 doesn't fly.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Find the zeroes of the denominator and check what happens to $y$ when $x$ becomes close to these. Also check what happens to $y$ when $x$ becomes really big (positive or negative).